# Custom Vertical trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

how to create 3 vertical buttons with a size of 44 by 44 and an indentation of 8 between them, as in the image without the library(preferably)

[image]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let leadingSpace = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") { (_, _, completionHandler) in
    // Actions for the first custom button
    completionHandler(true)
    }
    leadingSpace.backgroundColor = .clear
    leadingSpace.image = UIImage(systemName: "square.fill")
    leadingSpace.image?.withTintColor(.clear, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)

    let middleSpace = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") { (_, _, completionHandler) in
    // Actions for the second custom button
    completionHandler(true)
    }
    middleSpace.backgroundColor = .clear
    middleSpace.image = UIImage(systemName: "square.fill")
    middleSpace.image?.withTintColor(.clear, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)

    let trailingSpace = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") { (_, _, completionHandler) in
    // Actions for the third custom button
    completionHandler(true)
    }
    trailingSpace.backgroundColor = .clear
    trailingSpace.image = UIImage(systemName: "square.fill")
    trailingSpace.image?.withTintColor(.clear, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)

    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [leadingSpace, middleSpace, trailingSpace])
    configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false

    return configuration
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63301709/how-can-implement-two-vertical-button-in-swipe-to-delete-in-ios